# Download powershell script repository for offline

Tags: powershell, browser-automation

I'm looking to download all the Powershell scripts from the Microsoft script Gallery as they are retiring that site :(

There does not appear to be a way of doing that from the site itself and dont see an ftp site where I can select multiple files.

So I was looking to see if their was a programmatic way that could search the site for .ps1 files recursively ?

e.g. I see a powershell command  find-script   but there does not look to be a way to have it download what it finds.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you try `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Answer (score 1):

Once MS posted this notice, many have asked this same question. The answer initially was no. [Yet there once was a person who tried, got a lot of it and posted in on a github, but stopped seeding it for whatever reason](https://www.reddit.com/r/O365Reports/comments/gna07s/reminder_technet_gallery_retirement_in_june_2020/?user_id=55378458291).

***Others are trying to seed it, but you never know what else they are putting there. So, do that at your own risk.***

Hence the reason, when MS sees this stuff hit github, they delete it. remember MS owns github.

MS has no plans announced, to move these to another location. The plan as of all things considered, is they are just going to remove it period.

There is an ISE Add-on that you can install from the [Add-Ons Website](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2969.windows-powershell-ise-add-on-tools.aspx) using the Add-Ons menu option. It's called '[ScriptBrowser](http://Script%20Browser%20%20%09Microsoft%20CSS%09http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42525%20Jump)', which shows today 16,030 scripts available. Yet, you will note that the link of that website no longer works.

You can also install it using the normal PowerShell module convention.

```
 Find-Module -Name '*browser*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                         Repository Description                                                                                                         
------- ----                         ---------- -----------                                                                                                         
1.3.1.0 ScriptBrowser                PSGallery  Script Browser helps you search, download and manage 9000+ TechNet script samples from within your scripting envi...
1.0.1.0 ISEModuleBrowserAddon        PSGallery  Module Browser helps you search, download and manage modules from within your scripting environment, Windows Powe...
0.0.1   BrowserCacheCleanup          PSGallery  This is a destructive tool that removes all of the cached data that IE, Firefox and Chrome store                    
1.0.1   UniversalDashboard.UDBrowser PSGallery  Adding a react kawaii svg browser                                                                                   
0.6.6.0 PSBrowserBookmarks           PSGallery  Contains functions that export bookmarks from major browsers and import them into other browsers. Folder structur...
```

This will add a tab Commands Addon for you to browse the script repo and download them individually as well as provide a 'Download All' button.

This is not a complete list of all that is really there and not all will come down, meaning you will see errors like...

> 'Network error. Please check your internet connection'

... and there is no fix for that. Also, in a download all from any resource, you run the chance of getting bad stuff. A few of the downloads will trigger your Windows Defender or other AV solution as being malicious.

The last point, though ISE download screen will show the proper name and description, what gets downloaded it is a file set in a folder with a GUID as the name. So, you'd have to open each one to see what it really is.